# How to pass argument from functional component to class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props, react-functional-component

EDIT - I fixed this and posted the working code.

I'm working on a project and I am having a specific issue I can't figure out how to fix. I am displaying a list of champions images and when the user clicks on one of them (s) then it will change the page to display that champions name. Currently I can console.log any of the names without any issues which means my functional component Newchamp() is working! However I am having trouble passing an argument from NewChamp to the class component SpecificChamp. When I add the last line in Newchamp     return  and try to display it in SpecificChamp using {s} its undefined!

Is it possible to pass an argument from my functional class to my component class? if not how can I get the page to change to the specific image that is clicked? I am new to react and appreciate any help!

Can anyone please help me out with this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Champions.css';





class AllChamps extends Component  {

 render() {
let champion = this.props.champion;
        return(  
        <div className='champions'>
            <h1> all champions</h1>
            {Object.keys(this.props.champions).map((s) => (
                <div className='champs'     onClick={() => this.props.NewChamp({s, champion})}>        
                    <img   
                        alt='Champion Images'
                        src={`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/img/champion/${s}.png`}
                        onClick={this.props.onClick}
                     ></img>     
                    {s} 
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
)}}


class SpecificChamp extends Component  {

    render() {
       let champion = this.props.champion
       let Spec = champion[champion.length - 1];
        return (
            <div className='champions'>
                <h1> 1 champions</h1>
                <div className='champs'>
                    <button    onClick={this.props.onClick}></button>
                    {Spec}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
}




class Champions extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleAllChamps = this.handleAllChamps.bind(this);
        this.handleSpecificChamp = this.handleSpecificChamp.bind(this);
        this.NewChamp = this.NewChamp.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            champions: [],
            champion: [],
            clickedChamp: false,
            thisChamp: 'ahri'
        }}
NewChamp = (props) =>
 {
 let  s = props.s;
 props.champion.push(s);


fetch(`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion/${s}.json`)
    .then(response => { return response.json() })
    .then((response) => {
        Object.keys(response.data).map((a) => (s = a
        ))})
        fetch(`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion/${s}.json`)
            .then(response => { return response.json() })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(s)
                console.log(response.data)

                console.log(props.champion)

                
                
        })
        console.log(`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion/${s}.json`);

      

        

}

    handleAllChamps = (props) => {
        this.setState({ clickedChamp: true,
           })};
  
    handleSpecificChamp = () => {
        this.setState({ clickedChamp: false,
          })};

    componentDidMount(props) {
        const apiUrl = `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion.json`;
        fetch(apiUrl)
        .then(response => { return response.json() })
          .then((response) => {
          this.setState({
              champions: response.data
             
          }, () => (this.state.champions))
      
          return  
      })
   
  }

    render() {
   
        const clickedChamp = this.state.clickedChamp;
        let display;
        if (clickedChamp ) {
            display = <SpecificChamp champion={this.state.champion} onClick={this.handleSpecificChamp} s={this.state.thisChamp}/>;
        } else {
            display = <AllChamps  champions={this.state.champions} onClick={this.handleAllChamps}  NewChamp={this.NewChamp} thisChamp={this.state.thisChamp} champion={this.state.champion} />;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='champions'></div>

                {display}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Champions;
```

Comment: `onClick={() => NewChamp({s})}` what are you trying to do?

Comment: Use appropriate state management in NewChamp. You can't directly fetch the data there. 
Try using useEffect. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: @Adam I am trying to use it so that when the user clicks on one of the images it executes the NewChamp functions on the correct image which is named S. then pass S in so that I can use it to display the champions name later on

Comment: @tmh The data fetch works in the functions call thought since its console.logging the correct name of the champion I clicked. Are you saying that it just wont display because im not using useEffect?

Comment: @antiepic, yes, it will log response after fetch'ing in console, I was wondering what you are going to do with the response apart from logging. 
Btw you dont need to create jsx function to handle the onclick, you can just use simple function, I am referring to this `onClick={() => NewChamp({s})}`, if you want to render `NewChamp` then this is not the way to do.

Answer (score 2):

The render function in class component does not has any `props`. You should use props from `this` like what you have done with handle click.

```
class SpecificChamp extends Component  {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='champions'>
                <h1> 1 champions</h1>
                <div className='champs'>
                    <button    onClick={this.props.onClick}></button>
                    {this.props.s}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
}
```

Comment: Sorry I did have that on there not sure what happened. even with {this.props.s} nothing displays. When i do {console.log(this.props.s)} right under the h1 it says "undefined"